# radio button value not showing

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is the js code i am working on i need to fetch the question and answers this is the code for quiz.
**JS code is:**

```
var questions=[
{
    "q":"1.what is what?",
    "a":"aaa",
    "b":"bbb",
    "c":"ccc",
    "d":"ddd",
    "answer":"aaa"
},
{
    "q":"2.what is what?",
    "a":"aaa",
    "b":"bbb",
    "c":"ccc",
    "d":"ddd",
    "answer":"bbb"
},
{
    "q":"3.what is what?",
    "a":"aaa",
    "b":"bbb",
    "c":"ccc",
    "d":"ddd",
    "answer":"ccc"
},
{
    "q":"4.what is what?",
    "a":"aaa",
    "b":"bbb",
    "c":"ccc",
    "d":"ddd",
    "answer":"ddd"
}
];

var i=0;
function show(i){
  document.getElementById("ques").innerHTML=questions[i].q;
  document.getElementById("opt1").innerHTML=questions[i].a;
  document.getElementById("opt2").innerHTML=questions[i].b;
  document.getElementById("opt3").innerHTML=questions[i].c;
  document.getElementById("opt4").innerHTML=questions[i].d;
}
show(i);
```

I have written this js code to print the value of question from array above and answers in the form of radio button,but answers are not showing in radio button its empty.

**HTML code is:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
    Ques and Ans
</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="qa.css"> 
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <header>
        <div class="header_mid">
            <h1>BitsBridge</h1>
        </div>
    </header><br>
    <div id="main">
            <div id="ques"> 
            </div><br>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" id="opt1" name="options">
            </div><br>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" id="opt2" name="options">
            </div><br>  
            <div>
                <input type="radio" id="opt3" name="options">
            </div><br>
            <div>
            <input type="radio" id="opt4" name="options">
            </div><br>
        </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="qa.js">
    </script>
    <button class="submit" id="sub">Next</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Is there anything wrong i am doing as i am able to fetch the ques but not the answers.

Comment: Your HTML code doesn't look valid, try closing the <input> tags such as `<input type="radio" id="opt3" name="options" />`

Comment: @GiulioAmbrogi not helpful still same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually missing the `<label>` for the radio button (you can use `<span>` too). Just add some `<label>` element with the ids and then set the text into it.

```js
var questions=[
{
    "q":"1.what is what?",
    "a":"aaa",
    "b":"bbb",
    "c":"ccc",
    "d":"ddd",
    "answer":"aaa"
},
{
    "q":"2.what is what?",
    "a":"aaa",
    "b":"bbb",
    "c":"ccc",
    "d":"ddd",
    "answer":"bbb"
},
{
    "q":"3.what is what?",
    "a":"aaa",
    "b":"bbb",
    "c":"ccc",
    "d":"ddd",
    "answer":"ccc"
},
{
    "q":"4.what is what?",
    "a":"aaa",
    "b":"bbb",
    "c":"ccc",
    "d":"ddd",
    "answer":"ddd"
}
];

var i=0;
function show(i){
  document.getElementById("ques").innerHTML=questions[i].q;
  document.getElementById("opt1").innerHTML=questions[i].a;
  document.getElementById("lbl1").innerHTML = questions[i].a;
  document.getElementById("opt2").innerHTML=questions[i].b;
  document.getElementById("lbl2").innerHTML = questions[i].b;
  document.getElementById("opt3").innerHTML=questions[i].c;
  document.getElementById("lbl3").innerHTML = questions[i].c;
  document.getElementById("opt4").innerHTML=questions[i].d;
  document.getElementById("lbl4").innerHTML = questions[i].d;
}
show(i);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
    Ques and Ans
</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="qa.css"> 
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <header>
        <div class="header_mid">
            <h1>BitsBridge</h1>
        </div>
    </header><br>
    <div id="main">
            <div id="ques"> 
            </div><br>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" id="opt1" name="options">
                <label for='opt1' id='lbl1'></label>
            </div><br>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" id="opt2" name="options">
               <label for='opt2' id='lbl2'></label>
            </div><br>  
            <div>
                <input type="radio" id="opt3" name="options">
               <label for='opt3' id='lbl3'></label>
            </div><br>
            <div>
            <input type="radio" id="opt4" name="options">
            <label for='opt4' id='lbl4'></label>
            </div><br>
        </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="qa.js">
    </script>
    <button class="submit" id="sub">Next</button>

</body>
</html>
```

**NOTE**: Use `for` attribute so that the radio button is selected when you click on the text.

Comment: So, setting `innerHTML` on the inputs is not needed, right?

Comment: It is still needed @GolfWolf. Scroll the code snippet. You will see that there.

Comment: I [commented out](https://jsfiddle.net/v839ed15/) some lines and it still works OK.

Answer (score 0):

```
     <div id="main">
            <div id="ques"> 
            </div><br>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" id="a" name="options"/>
                <span id="o1"></span>
            </div><br>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" id="b" name="options"/>
                <span id="o2"></span>
            </div><br>  
            <div>
                <input type="radio" id="c" name="options"/>
                <span id="o3"></span>
            </div><br>
            <div>
                <input type="radio" id="d" name="options"/>
                <span id="o4"></span>
            </div><br>
    </div>
```

Just add another id using span tag in html code for mapping.
and in js code:

```
document.getElementById("ques").innerHTML=questions[i].q;
document.getElementById("o1").innerHTML=questions[i].a;
document.getElementById("o2").innerHTML=questions[i].b;
document.getElementById("o3").innerHTML=questions[i].c;
document.getElementById("o4").innerHTML=questions[i].d;
```

this solve the issue,the problem was with id mapping.

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues:

1. as I already commented, fix your html markup for inputs
2. You are trying to use `.innerHTML` on an `input` element, which is not valid

To achieve your goal I would change the box model slightly, adding  a `label` element next to your `input`s and then inserting the answer into that label instead of the input element.

See my example: https://codepen.io/giulioambrogi/pen/QaYyzw

Comment: with due respect sir i am still a beginner and the code in above link is slightly complex for me.Thanks

Comment: @mkp24 the codepen snippet is exactly *your code* (copied and pasted from here), I've only applied the changes mentioned above

Comment: sir the code showing there is a table code @giulioambrogi